# Magnolia CSS and images throwing NPE 500 Error

Tags: magnolia

Unable to use Magnolia login.css and magnolia images. When I try to Magnolia author instance, the CSS and Images are throwing 500 error. Following exception trace is shown on the browser window. Any clues as to how could I fix it? I am using Magnolia version 4.5

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        info.magnolia.module.cache.cachepolicy.Default.shouldCache(Default.java:97)
        info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:133)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:76)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:86)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
        info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:86)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:75)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
        info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:93)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:85)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.CosMultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(CosMultipartRequestFilter.java:87)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:61)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:103)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:131)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:83)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:67)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:91)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:108)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:108)
        info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:94)
```

The maven dependencies being used by me are :

```
<dependency>
      <name>core</name>
      <version>4.1/*</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <name>adminInterface</name>
      <version>4.1/*</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <name>templating</name>
      <version>4.1/*</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <name>fckEditor</name>
      <version>4.1/*</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <name>blossom</name>
      <version>2.0/*</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use artifcat from magnolia to build your project, take a look at this: http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects